# Set tab control style on managed TabControl

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce, tabcontrol

Is it possible to set a tab control style like [TSC_BUTTONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920740.aspx) on a managed TabControl?

Windows CE 6 / .NET CF 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the caveat that I'm not specifically done this style change (though I've done plenty of others), according to the docs [TCS_BUTTONS is a supported style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920740.aspx).  Since the managed TabControl is simply a wrapper around the native one, you should be able to P/Invoke SetWindowLong with GWL_STYLE and adjust this (probably in the constructor of a TabControl-derived custom control).

Comment: That worked - thanks. Somewhat related: Is there a property that disables the drawing of the single pixel border around the TabControl?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
const long TSC_BUTTONS = 0x0100;

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
static extern void SetWindowLong(IntPtr ptr, int index, long value);

// In constructor:
SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_STYLE, TSC_BUTTONS);
```